# Standard way to call `ffsl` in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, glibc

The [`ffsl` function](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/ffs.3.html) is part of glibc. In GCC it is also available via [`__builtin_ffsl`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html). It returns the index of the least significant bit in a long.

Is there a way to access this functionality in standards-conforming C++ code? I would like to get at these versions (if available) because they are written in assembly for high performance. (Most architectures provide an instruction for this function or similar.)

Comment: It is not standard conforming. How could you access it in a standard conforming code?

Comment: A way to do it [was proposed](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3864.html)

Comment: @skypjack I was hoping that a function to do the same thing exists somewhere in a standard header, whose implementation presumably does "the right thing" depending on the architecture or OS etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no standard function to achieve this and each compiler typically provides it's own intrinsic to compute ffs (see e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Find_first_set#Tool_and_library_support) for relatively complete list). So your best take would be to do a wrapper

```
#ifdef __GNUC__
#  define ffs(x) __builtin_ffs(x)
#elif __INTEL_COMPILER
#  define ffs(x) _bit_scan_forward(x)
...
```

Also note that `__builtin_ffs` and `ffs(3)` may generate non-equivalent code (I'd use compiler intrinsic as these tend to be better optimized by compiler, on the other hand GCC intrinsics are not always well optimized).