# Is there a way to solve for an unknown exponent in c where the base is always 2 without math.h?

Tags: c

My current (bad) solution:

```
void initialization(void) {
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < pageSize; i++) {
        if (2 << i == pageSize) {
            offset = i;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Example:
pageSize = 4096, Solve for x in, pageSize = 2^x

I feel like there should be a much better way if doing this without a loop and without `math.h`. Especially since the base is always 2 and there's a lot of stuff with bit shifting involving powers of 2.

Comment: `__builtin_ctz(pageSize) - 1`, maybe.

Comment: By the way `2 << i` is 2 to the power of i+1, not just to the power of i. 2 already has a shift built into it in some sense.

Comment: What about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41369765/standard-way-to-call-ffsl-in-c

Comment: If My guess about ffsl is right then this might be useful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Find_first_set#Tool_and_library_support

Comment: That's an infinite loop if pagesize turns out not to be a power of 2.

Comment: `for (int i=0;;) if (pageSize >> i == 1) return i;` although there are faster versions.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah I found the solution on http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html from that question. My problem was I didn't really know what I was asking for. I want to find the highest bit set and that page has multiple solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was I didn't really know what I was looking for. I needed to find the highest bit set (or most significant bit set, MSB). Multiple solutions can be found on [Bit Twiddling Hacks](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html). Hopefully my poorly worded question helps others Googling similarly poorly worded questions at some point.

For my specific purpose this solution works:

```
int v = pageSize; // 32-bit integer to find the log base 2 of
int r; // result of log_2(v) goes here
union { unsigned int u[2]; double d; } t; // temp

t.u[__ORDER_LITTLE_ENDIAN__==LITTLE_ENDIAN] = 0x43300000;
t.u[__ORDER_LITTLE_ENDIAN__!=LITTLE_ENDIAN] = v;
t.d -= 4503599627370496.0;
r = (t.u[__ORDER_LITTLE_ENDIAN__==LITTLE_ENDIAN] >> 20) - 0x3FF;
```

Answer (score 0):

clang is capable of recognizing what this function does:

```
unsigned int log2i(unsigned int n) {
    unsigned int i = 0;

    while (n >>= 1) {
        i++;
    }

    return i;
}
```

```
log2i:
        shr     edi
        lzcnt   ecx, edi
        mov     eax, 32
        sub     eax, ecx
        ret
```

But since you have an exact power of two, in practice, it’s probably fine and better to use a GCC/clang/others builtin even if it’s not standard C:

```
unsigned int log2Exact(unsigned int n) {
    return __builtin_ctz(n);
}
```

```
log2Exact:
        tzcnt   eax, edi
        ret
```

Comment: Just out of interest, what method do you use to see the disassembly?

Comment: @Will: https://godbolt.org/

Comment: Thanks! That is so useful